# Can I call GitHub Copilot using APIs?

Tags: python, openai-api, large-language-model, github-copilot

I would like to use GitHub copilot just like i can use other LLMs using APIs. Is it possible to do so? If it is, where do I find the required API-key ?

There is no resource available on GitHub and only shows that we can use APIs for enterprise account management

Comment: Specifically, this should do what you're looking for: https://github.com/B00TK1D/copilot-api

Comment: I love how you've written the api yourself...but is there nothing official?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, there is no officially documented Copilot API.  The upside to that is, their undocumented API is also free as long as you have Copilot access.

Comment: where can i find this undocumented API?

Comment: I found it by reverse engineering the Copilot Vim plugin.  I'd recommend taking a look through the code I linked above if you'd like to see how their API works more.  It uses nearly the exact same specification as the OpenAI API, just with a different endpoint and extra steps for auth.